# R:creating a data frame inside if statement

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create a data frame within the `if` statement , but when I use this data frame in the `else` scope I get the following error:

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Here is part of my code:

```
for(i in 1:numOfTrays){
if (i == 1){
  parameters <- c(Qin=Qin,A=A)
  state <- c(h=h0)
  time <- seq(0,200,by=1)
  out <- ode(y= state, func = FluidH, parms = parameters, times = time)
  Qout <- cbind(out[,1],VFRoutput((out[,2])))
  colnames(Qout)<-c("time","Qout")
  Qin <- as.data.frame(Qout)
  #write.csv(Qin,"Qin")
}
else{

  for (j in 1:length(Qin$Qout)){
    h <- h0 + ((Qin$Qout[j]-VFRoutput(h0))/A)*Qin$time[j]
```

I tried to make `Qin` global with the `<<-` operator but when I tried to print `Qin$Qout` from the `if` statement I got the same error.

Any solutions?

Comment: If you post your data using `dput()` on your data objects it will make it much easier to replicate.

Comment: Don't use the `<<-` operator. You don't need it here (really, you almost never need it anywhere).

Comment: @Gregor, say there is an object `a` created by function `b` and `a` would be used by function `c` which gets called just after `b`. Wouldn't `<<-` be useful in such cases. Or you would prefer something else like `assign` or `list2env` instead of `<<-`?

Comment: Functions should "create" objects. Functions should return objects which are assigned. If `b` creates something useful outside of `b`, then `b` should `return` it. If `c` needs something that is loaded by a package, then it should be included as an input argument to `c`. This is how functional programming is supposed to work.

Comment: If you start putting things in the global environment (no matter how you do it, `<<-`, `assign`, `list2env`, or anything else) you make your code very hard to work with. What if I already have something in my global environment that has the name you happen to use? Your function just over-wrote it. What if I want to run the functions 10 times and compare the results and intermediate steps? Can't do it, your function overwrote everything. What if I want to run your function in parallel? Can't do it, your function must be run sequentially....

Comment: What if I write a function that uses your function? Well, I hope you're careful about where you're assigning things (parent frame, global environment...). If not, it will probably be hopeless to debug.

Comment: Either you are running a loop or not understanding the concept of `if` - `else`, given your comments it might be the latter

Comment: I am using the if-else inside a loop, (i edited the code above). my problem is with Qin: i creat this data frame in the if(i==1) and i want to use it in the else and calculate things on one of its subsets , but keep getting the error that Qin is an  atomic vector

Comment: Why are you reusing the name `Qin` for different things? Seems confusing and like a potential source of bugs. For example, the first line in your `if()` is `parameters <- c(Qin=Qin,A=A)`, showing that `Qin` *must* already exist (and isn't a data frame, the way you're using it), but a few lines later you set `Qin <- as.data.frame(Qout)`. Maybe pick a different name and things will be less confusing? Or at least post enough code to make your example runnable. No one can run anything you posted without sample values for `numOfTrays`, `Qin`, `A`, `h0`...

Comment: Maybe replace `Qout <- cbind(out[,1],VFRoutput((out[,2])));
  colnames(Qout)<-c("time","Qout");
  Qin <- as.data.frame(Qout);` with `Qin = data.frame(time = out[, 1], Qout = VFRoutput(out[, 2]))` to clean it up a little?

Answer (score 0):

While your example is not reproducible, I would venture a guess that `Qout` exists before the `if` statement as a matrix or some sort (perhaps with no column names). Here's a reproducible example:

```
Qout <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

chk <- TRUE

if (chk) {
  out <- as.data.frame(Qout)
} else {
  Qout$col1
}

Qout <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
chk <- FALSE

if (chk) {
  out <- as.data.frame(Qout)
} else {
  Qout$col1
}

Error in Qout$col1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

So you need to make sure that in `else` statement, you're dealing with an object that supports `$` subsetting - like a `data.frame`.

Comment: if i compare your example to my code i writing out$col1 not Qout$col1 and im still getting the error that out is an atomic vector